# Native Phonegap, download and createfile, dynamicly named file, and return path

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Problem consist of my lack of knowledge for Javascript afaik.
When I write:

```
function startOnDevice(){
   var path = document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
}
```

How can I then pass a "string" of what the name of the file should be? (ei. to onDeviceReady, and then further down the tree.

then after it has been passed to onDeviceReady. it needs to be passed to, onFSSuccess:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
//what do we have in cache already?
$("#status").html("Checking your local cache....");    
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, null);    
}

function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("dk.lector.html5Generic",{
        create:true
    },gotDir,onError);
}
```

and then onFSSuccess needs to give the value back to the variable path somehow.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a new version as you've updated the code in the question:

```
var file = "foo.txt";

function onDeviceReady() {
  //what do we have in cache already?
  $("#status").html("Checking your local cache....");
  alert("file is " + file);    
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
  function (fileSystem) {
    onFSSuccess(fileSystem, file); // use file variable from above and pass as second param.
  }, null);    
}

function onFSSuccess(fileSystem, file) {
  alert("file is " + file);
  fileSystem.root.getDirectory("dk.lector.html5Generic",{
    create:true
   },gotDir,onError);
}
```

Comment: function init(){
var path = startOnDevice;
}.   and then in onFSSuccess(file){return file}? .. Ei. missing how i get the path returned :)

Comment: Did more updates, I onFSSuccess had a value passed to it from the API(it seems)

Comment: I've updated to include the return value. I don't quite follow your comment previously?

Comment: Cool, that looks like what I need. An extended question. can I now call my startOnDevice on runtime ?, I think I can't, but ain't sure.
If I should make this run at runtime, example a button click initiates it, is that an easy update? :)

Comment: you should only call the startOnDevice function once - normally in the body onload event.

Comment: Okay, i'll do that and then set a global variable I guess